# Acumatica and Visual Studio 2022 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, acumatica

Is there any official or unofficial details about compatibility of Acumatica with Visual Studio 2022 for customization development and integration?  Any issues with developers using it now that it is released?

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for no issue. Only issue is that Acuminator has not been ported to VS2022 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is none yet at the moment. I am also looking Acumatica Framework Tools to install for VS 2022. The tool is relatively new at the moment. We'll wait until the tools are released for VS 2022.

Hope you find this helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can build the extension by getting the source: https://github.com/Acumatica/Acuminator/tree/VS2022

Answer (score 0):

Use Acuminator. It is the official extension for the development with Acumatica Framework.

Regarding support of Visual Studio 2022.
A new Acuminator version 3.0.0 was released in April. It supports Visual Studio 2022.
Checkout its page in the marketplace:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Acumatica.Acuminator